# Fetch huge API response without blocking the rendering of the page in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, axios, fetch, nuxt.js

I have a dynamic page in Nuxt where I use Fetch and Axios to get all the data I need like photos/text my problem is that the API is quite long (more than 3800 lines).
The page loads with nothing appearing during 11 seconds so I was wondering if it's possible to not wait the end of the fetch call and make appearing the first results while the other one continue loading.

I try chaining fetch call with no success. I hope someone could guide me for the solution.

Here is my fetch:

```js
async fetch() {
  let path = this.$nuxt.context.route.path
  this.response = await axios.get(
    `/api${path}`, 
    {
      headers: {
        'X-AUTH-TOKEN': process.env.SECURE_TOKEN, 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }}
  ).then((res) => {
    this.models = res.data.content;
  })
},
fetchOnServer: true,
```

Comment: Are you using fetch in component or page?

Comment: i use Fetch in the page

Comment: I recommend using asyncData. This will run on the server, so it will increase the speed. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/

Comment: Thank you Amini im trying it now your right but AsyncData block the route change until its resolved and i need to have the route changing quickly

Comment: What do you mean by "block the route change until its resolved" and why you want to have the route changing quickly?

Comment: ooo i need the rout change quickly coz when user click on a links with async data the switch to the new page is too long so often they left website thinking it snot working

Comment: does this solves it? `asyncData({ route })`

Comment: i still have the waiting on route change maybe if i can limit the number of response that asyncdata is getting on route change like 20 instead of the full reponse, it will be quicker do you know how to limit AsyncData only to the 20 first results Amini ?

Comment: Are you using nuxt3 or 2?

Comment: i use Nuxt 2 but i wish soon move to Nuxt 3

Comment: I don't think you can do this in nuxt2 but there is an option for it in nuxt3. You can not limit the api unless the backend provides queries in order to limit the data.

Comment: ooo i understand Amini Thank you to took time to answer me i will check if the API got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, you will not need to fetch all of them.
Pagination is still the way to go because loading 3800 elements on a webpage is not the way to go if you're display only 10 or even 100 of them (will be too heavy to handle JS-wise and not useful anyhow).

There are ways to achieve that with some advanced patterns but still, totally not needed here.

What you should do is look for some pagination on the API. If it's not available, I still recommend that you do that ahead of time rather than on client-side.
Also, using some infinite-scroll is quite a good idea to paginate 10 elements on each iteration.

Some solutions on how to implement that are available in my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+infinite+scroll).
Otherwise, here are some [useful packages](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#infinite-scroll) for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the advices Kissu ...i will go with the vue-infinite-loading